# Bootstrap 5 modal is not closing from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

> Blockquote

In ASP.NET CORE MVC, I am using bootstrap 5 modal to show loader while loading data from the server. Code is as below,

Added hidden link,

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" id="hiddenBtn" hidden>Click</a>

<div id=placeHolderElement"></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="popup" data-bs-backdrop="static" 
 data-bs-keyboard="false">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-body">
         <partial name="_loader" model='new LoaderVM{ message = 
          "Loading"}'/>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <div>
```

JQuery code -

```
$(function(){

   $('#hiddenBtn').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
       url: 'some url',
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'html',
       beforeSend: function(){
        $('#popup').modal('show');
        } 
        success: function(response){
          $('#placeHolderElement').html(response);

         var dataFromServer = getDataFromServer();
         // use dataFromServer and find the table in placeHolderElement div and append 
         // rows
         
          $('#popup').modal('hide');
         }
        complete: function(){$('#popup').modal('hide');}

         });
     });

    $('#hiddenBtn').trigger('click');
 });
```

Modal opens successfully and keeps showing. It doesn't close even if the data is loaded in the background and 'complete' is triggered. How can I close the modal once the data is loaded on the page?

Comment: typo in type : 'get' in ajax call.

Comment: It should be `method: "GET"` as @SuchandraT said

Comment: I don't think it works like this any more in BS5. You need to get the actual modal instance: `bootstrap.Modal.getInstance('#popup').hide();`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed - 'get' or 'GET', 'post' or 'POST' it doesn't matter.

Comment: If I remove `var dataFromServer = getDataFromServer();`, Your code will work successfully, Because you don't provide related code, So i can't figure out what's wrong with this code.

Comment: @XinranShen getDataFromServer(); gets the json values from server. And I am creating table rows dynamically and adding these rows to the table in the partial view which is attached to the div - 'placeHolderElement' at the beginning of the function as 

 $('#placeHolderElement').html(response);

Comment: Can you provide the code related to this?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#via-javascript